# Edit specific menu items in template

Tags: theming, routes

In my theme I'd like to have complete control over my menus. I'd like to apply specific classes and wrap the menu however I like. I was thinking I could do this within a template. I see that you can print the menu with this:

```
<?php
$menu = menu_navigation_links('menu-your-custom-menu-name');
print theme('links__menu_your_custom_menu_name', array('links' => $menu));
?>
```

But I'm not sure how to edit the individual items within the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Menu attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module is for what you want. Some details from its project page:

> This simple module allows you to specify some additional attributes
>   for menu items such as id, name, class, style, and rel.